# Matrix norm $T:l_{\infty}^{2}\rightarrow l_{\infty}^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by the $2\times2$
matrix $(a_{jk})_{j,k=1}^{2},\: a_{jk}\in\mathbb{R}$.  Let $l_{\infty}^{2}$
denote $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ equipped with the norm $||x||_{\infty}=\max(|x_{1}|,|x_{2}|)$
for $x=(x_{1},x_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Let $T:l_{\infty}^{2}\rightarrow l_{\infty}^{2}$.
Find the operator norm $||T||$.

I guess it should be $||T||=\max\{|a_{11}|+|a_{12}|,|a_{21}|+|a_{22}|\}$,
but I am not sure how to show that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let $x \in \ell^2_\infty$, $||Tx|| = \max_i|(Tx)_i|$. Then we have
$$
\begin{align*} 
   ||Tx|| &= \max_i|(Tx)_i|\\
          &= \max_i|a_{i1}x_1 + a_{i2}x_2|\\
          &\leq \max_i(|a_{i1}| + |a_{i2}|)||x||.
\end{align*}
$$
So $||T|| \le \max\{|a_{11}| + |a_{12}|, |a_{21}| + |a_{22}|\}$. For the other bound, choose $i$ such that $\max\{|a_{11}| + |a_{12}|, |a_{21}| + |a_{22}|\} = |a_{i1}| + |a_{i2}|$. Let $x_j =  \frac{|a_{ij}|}{a_{ij}}$, then $||x|| = 1$ and 
$$
\begin{align*} 
   ||Tx|| &\ge \max_i|(Tx)_i|\\
          &= \max_i|a_{i1}x_1 + a_{i2}x_2|\\
          &= \max_i(|a_{i1}| + |a_{i2}|).
\end{align*}
$$
So $||T|| = \max\{|a_{11}| + |a_{12}|, |a_{21}| + |a_{22}|\}$,

AB,

Comment: Your `align*` environments do not render properly for me. I tried to fix them, but for some reason I didn't manage to achieve that

Comment: I have tried also to fix. Perhaps its an issue of a MathJax-Update or sth like that?